# Trigger Instead OF insert en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, trigger

Disculpen a ver si me pueden ayudar con lo siguiente: Estoy migrando un trigger de Oracle a SQL SERVER.
Estoy construyendo el trigger y lo que quiero hacer es que si en la tabla1 llamada location ingresa un número de teléfono repetido me lo mueva a la tabla2 history y que luego borre el registro del teléfono duplicado en  location. Dejando solo el actual. 
Tengo entendido que en SQL SERVER no se maneja el before, por eso me cree una vista para unir las dos tablas y utilizar el instead of.
He notado que cuando inserto registros en la vista solo me llena la tabla1 location la cual tiene un ID autoincrementable. Me di cuenta que el problema esta en el join ya que inserted no toma el autoincrementable. ¿Cómo podría solventar este problema?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

```sql
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_location] 
ON [dbo].[LOCATION_VIEW]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
DECLARE
        @v_call table(
        [TELEFONO] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
        [SYS_DATE] [datetime]);
BEGIN

 INSERT INTO LOCATION(TELEFONO) SELECT TELEFONO FROM INSERTed;


 INSERT INTO @v_call (L.TELEFONO) SELECT L.TELEFONO FROM LOCATION_VIEW L JOIN INSERTed AS i ON latest.ID = i.ID WHERE latest.TELEFONO = i.TELEFONO;


    begin try
    INSERT INTO history (TELEFONO) SELECT TELEFONO FROM location WHERE TELEFONO = (SELECT TELEFONO FROM @v_call);
    end try     
    begin catch
        INSERT INTO LOCATION_ERRORS (objeto, error, line_error) values ('tg_cellphone_location - INSERT',ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_NUMBER())
    end catch

    begin try
    DELETE FROM location WHERE TELEFONO = (select TELEFONO from @v_call) and SYS_DATE <> (select SYS_DATE from @v_call);
    end try
    begin catch
        INSERT INTO LOCATION_ERRORS (objeto, error, line_error) values ('tg_cellphone_location - delete',ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_NUMBER())
    end catch
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo modificando la linea del `join`, agregando la función `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` quedando así de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO @v_call (L.TELEFONO) SELECT L.TELEFONO FROM LOCATION_VIEW L JOIN INSERTed AS i ON latest.ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE latest.TELEFONO = i.TELEFONO;
```